# How do you quickly sum large numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, performance, addition, scientific-computing

I'm trying to write some python code to solve a particular energy minimization problem and I have run into a bottleneck adding a lot of very large 4-dimensional arrays together.

I'm given some Lagrangian for the problem from which I can define an update function in terms of derivatives of the thing to be updated. I find these derivatives with finite differences, which is relatively quick. Then I input them into a function which I will use to update n (a vector field). Every variable below is a numpy array of dimension 200x200x200x3 except dx,dy,dz,k11,k22,k33, and q0 which are floats.

I've tried speeding it up using numba and cython and that gave some minimal speed ups (maybe 10%). Though I'm not to familiar with them so I may have not implemented them correctly. Furthermore, I have typed this problem in MatLab and it seems to do the same operations about twice as fast. Ideally I would like to stick to using python. Is there anyway to speed up the arithmetic of the arrays? Thank you for your time.

```py
import numpy as np

def F(n,xE,yE,zE,xB,yB,zB,dx,dy,dz,k11,k22,k33,q0):

    #some code to calculate derivitives
    xn=n[:,:,:,0]
    yn=n[:,:,:,1]
    zn=n[:,:,:,2]

    xnx=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0)-np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0))/(2*dx)
    xny=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,1)-np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,1))/(2*dy)
    xnz=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,2)-np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,2))/(2*dz)
    ynx=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0)-np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0))/(2*dx)
    yny=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,1)-np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,1))/(2*dy)
    ynz=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,2)-np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,2))/(2*dz)
    znx=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0)-np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0))/(2*dx)
    zny=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,1)-np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,1))/(2*dy)
    znz=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,2)-np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,2))/(2*dz)



    xnxx=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0)+np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0)-2*xn[:,:,:])/dx**2
    xnyy=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,1)+np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,1)-2*xn[:,:,:])/dx**2
    xnzz=(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,2)+np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,2)-2*xn[:,:,:])/dx**2
    ynxx=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0)+np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0)-2*yn[:,:,:])/dy**2
    ynyy=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,1)+np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,1)-2*yn[:,:,:])/dy**2
    ynzz=(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,2)+np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,2)-2*yn[:,:,:])/dy**2
    znxx=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0)+np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0)-2*zn[:,:,:])/dz**2
    znyy=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,1)+np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,1)-2*zn[:,:,:])/dz**2
    znzz=(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,2)+np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,2)-2*zn[:,:,:])/dz**2


    xnxy=(np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0),1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,1)+np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,1))/(4*dx*dy)
    xnxz=(np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,2))/(4*dx*dz)
    xnyz=(np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,1),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],1,1),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,1),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(xn[:,:,:],-1,1),-1,2))/(4*dy*dz)
    ynxy=(np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0),1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,1)+np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,1))/(4*dx*dy)
    ynxz=(np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,2))/(4*dx*dz)
    ynyz=(np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,1),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],1,1),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,1),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(yn[:,:,:],-1,1),-1,2))/(4*dy*dz)
    znxy=(np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0),1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,1)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,1)+np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,1))/(4*dx*dy)
    znxz=(np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,0),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,0),-1,2))/(4*dx*dz)
    znyz=(np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,1),1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],1,1),-1,2)-np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,1),1,2)+np.roll(np.roll(zn[:,:,:],-1,1),-1,2))/(4*dy*dz)


    #code to find the minimization steps
    x_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxx + ynxy + znxz) - 1.0*k22*(ynz - zny)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*ynz + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*zny - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*zny - (xnz - znx)*yny + (ynz - zny)*xny + (xnyy - ynxy)*zn - (xnyz - znxy)*yn + (ynyz - znyy)*xn)*zn + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znz - (xnz - znx)*ynz + (ynz - zny)*xnz + (xnyz - ynxz)*zn - (xnzz - znxz)*yn + (ynzz - znyz)*xn)*yn + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*(xny - ynx) + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*(xnz - znx)) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*xny + ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*yny + ((xny - ynx)*xny - (ynz - zny)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*xn - (ynyz - znyy)*zn)*xn + ((xny - ynx)*yny + (xnz - znx)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*yn + (xnyz - znxy)*zn)*yn) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*znz + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*xnz + ((xny - ynx)*ynz + (xnz - znx)*znz + (xnyz - ynxz)*yn + (xnzz - znxz)*zn)*zn + ((xnz - znx)*xnz + (ynz - zny)*ynz + (xnzz - znxz)*xn + (ynzz - znyz)*yn)*xn) + xB + xE

    y_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxy + ynyy + znyz) + k22*(xnz - znx)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*xnz - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*znx + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znx - (xnz - znx)*ynx + (ynz - zny)*xnx + (xnxy - ynxx)*zn - (xnxz - znxx)*yn + (ynxz - znxy)*xn)*zn - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znz - (xnz - znx)*ynz + (ynz - zny)*xnz + (xnyz - ynxz)*zn - (xnzz - znxz)*yn + (ynzz - znyz)*xn)*xn + k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*(xny - ynx) + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*(ynz - zny)) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*xnx + ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*ynx + ((xny - ynx)*xnx - (ynz - zny)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*xn - (ynxz - znxy)*zn)*xn + ((xny - ynx)*ynx + (xnz - znx)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*yn + (xnxz - znxx)*zn)*yn) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*znz - ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*ynz + ((xny - ynx)*xnz - (ynz - zny)*znz + (xnyz - ynxz)*xn - (ynzz - znyz)*zn)*zn - ((xnz - znx)*xnz + (ynz - zny)*ynz + (xnzz - znxz)*xn + (ynzz - znyz)*yn)*yn) + yB + yE

    z_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxz + ynyz + znzz) - 1.0*k22*(xny - ynx)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*xny + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*ynx - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znx - (xnz - znx)*ynx + (ynz - zny)*xnx + (xnxy - ynxx)*zn - (xnxz - znxx)*yn + (ynxz - znxy)*xn)*yn + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*zny - (xnz - znx)*yny + (ynz - zny)*xny + (xnyy - ynxy)*zn - (xnyz - znxy)*yn + (ynyz - znyy)*xn)*xn - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*(ynz - zny) - ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*(xnz - znx)) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*zny - ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*yny + ((xny - ynx)*xny - (ynz - zny)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*xn - (ynyz - znyy)*zn)*zn - ((xnz - znx)*xny + (ynz - zny)*yny + (xnyz - znxy)*xn + (ynyz - znyy)*yn)*yn) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*znx + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*xnx + ((xny - ynx)*ynx + (xnz - znx)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*yn + (xnxz - znxx)*zn)*zn + ((xnz - znx)*xnx + (ynz - zny)*ynx + (xnxz - znxx)*xn + (ynxz - znxy)*yn)*xn) + zB + zE

    return x_update,y_update,z_update


#COMPUTATIONAL PARAMETERS
#define computational size of cell
blocks_x=50
blocks_y=50
blocks_z=50
#define experimental size of cell in micro-meters
dimx=float(1e-6)
dimy=float(1e-6)
dimz=float(1e-6)
#define step size
dx=dimx/blocks_x
dy=dimy/blocks_y
dz=dimz/blocks_z




#EXPERIMENTAL PARAMETERS
#director profile
n = np.zeros((blocks_x,blocks_y,blocks_z,3))
n[:,:,:,0]=1

#elastic constants
k11=float(1e-12)        #splay
k22=float(1e-12)        #twist 
k33=float(1e-12)        #bend
k24=float(1e-12)        #saddle splay

#twistedness
pitch = float(1e-6)/1.5
q0 =2*np.pi/pitch  #chiral wavenumber

#applied magnetic field
E=np.zeros((blocks_x,blocks_y,blocks_z,3))
E[:,:,:,1]=float(1e2)

#applied magnetic field
B=np.zeros((blocks_x,blocks_y,blocks_z,3))
B[:,:,:,2]=float(1e2)
#viscocity


xE=E[:,:,:,0]
yE=E[:,:,:,1]
zE=E[:,:,:,2]
xB=B[:,:,:,0]
yB=B[:,:,:,1]
zB=B[:,:,:,2]

%timeit -n 100 F(n,xE,yE,zE,xB,yB,zB,dx,dy,dz,k11,k22,k33,q0)
```

EDIT:

Updated code so it is now runnable. The magic command %timeit outputs 107ms per loop out of 100 with an input, n ,of size (50,50,50,3). One can modify the size of the input by redefining blocks_x, blocks_y and blocks_z.

Comment: How about `xny`, `znx`, ... are they constants or are they also 3-d arrays?

Comment: they are are arrays

Comment: Please give a complete runable example. This includes the definition of all arrays and your timings. It may be also good to provide the calculations of the derivatives, because calculating temporary arrays like xnxx can maybe completely avoided (and avoiding temporary arrays is usually the way to go here)

Comment: @max9111 I've just included a functioning version. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `numpy.sum()` feature with the arrays instead of the long logic stream? You can also specify that to run along a single axis (e.g. axis=2)

Comment: I created a new array containing all the terms listed above (e.g np.array([xnx,xnx*ynx,....])) and then I used the function np.sum(), but found that it was twice as slow (%timeit) as just using the above.

Comment: If you are working on a system with an Nvidia GPU, look into the cupy library.  It works very similarly to NumPy, but uses the GPU for compute instead of CPU.  In most instances of arrays I work with, 2000x7200x39 arrays, it is MUCH faster than CPU calculations on a 2.6 GHz Xeon CPU.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple repeat terms in those equations. *Factor them out* to individual variables and only do them once.

```
def F(n,xE,yE,zE,xB,yB,zB,dx,dy,dz,k11,k22,k33,q0):

    #some code to calculate derivitives

    # common terms for minimization steps
    alpha = (xny - ynx)    # 32 of these
    alpha1 = alpha*zn

    beta = (xnz - znx)    # 32 of these
    beta1 = beta*yn

    gamma = (ynz - zny)    # 32 of these
    gamma1 = gamma*xn

    kappa = (q0 - alpha1 + beta1 - gamma1)    # 10 of these

    theta = (xnyz - znxy)    # 4 each of this group
    zeta = (xnyz - ynxz)
    rho = (xnyy - ynxy)
    tau = (xnxy - ynxx)
    upsilon = (xnxz - znxx)
    phi = (ynyz - znyy)
    chi = (ynxz - znxy)
    psi = (xnzz - znxz)
    omega = (ynzz - znyz)

    #code to find the minimization steps
    x_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxx + ynxy + znxz) - 1.0*k22*gamma*kappa - 1.0*k22*kappa*ynz + 1.0*k22*kappa*zny - 1.0*k22*(alpha*zny - beta*yny + gamma*xny + rho*zn - theta*yn + phi*xn)*zn + 1.0*k22*(alpha*znz - beta*ynz + gamma*xnz + zeta*zn - psi*yn + omega*xn)*yn + k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*alpha + (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*beta) - 1.0*k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*xny + (alpha*yn + beta*zn)*yny + (alpha*xny - gamma*zny + rho*xn - phi*zn)*xn + (alpha*yny + beta*zny + rho*yn + theta*zn)*yn) - 1.0*k33*((alpha*yn + beta*zn)*znz + (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*xnz + (alpha*ynz + beta*znz + zeta*yn + psi*zn)*zn + (beta*xnz + gamma*ynz + psi*xn + omega*yn)*xn) + xB + xE

    y_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxy + ynyy + znyz) + k22*beta*kappa + 1.0*k22*kappa*xnz - 1.0*k22*kappa*znx + 1.0*k22*(alpha*znx - beta*ynx + gamma*xnx + tau*zn - upsilon*yn + chi*xn)*zn - 1.0*k22*(alpha*znz - beta*ynz + gamma*xnz + zeta*zn - psi*yn + omega*xn)*xn + k33*((alpha*yn + beta*zn)*alpha + (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*gamma) + k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*xnx + (alpha*yn + beta*zn)*ynx + (alpha*xnx - gamma*znx + tau*xn - chi*zn)*xn + (alpha*ynx + beta*znx + tau*yn + upsilon*zn)*yn) + k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*znz - (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*ynz + (alpha*xnz - gamma*znz + zeta*xn - omega*zn)*zn - (beta*xnz + gamma*ynz + psi*xn + omega*yn)*yn) + yB + yE

    z_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxz + ynyz + znzz) - 1.0*k22*alpha*kappa - 1.0*k22*kappa*xny + 1.0*k22*kappa*ynx - 1.0*k22*(alpha*znx - beta*ynx + gamma*xnx + tau*zn - upsilon*yn + chi*xn)*yn + 1.0*k22*(alpha*zny - beta*yny + gamma*xny + rho*zn - theta*yn + phi*xn)*xn - 1.0*k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*gamma - (alpha*yn + beta*zn)*beta) - 1.0*k33*((alpha*xn - gamma*zn)*zny - (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*yny + (alpha*xny - gamma*zny + rho*xn - phi*zn)*zn - (beta*xny + gamma*yny + theta*xn + phi*yn)*yn) + k33*((alpha*yn + beta*zn)*znx + (beta*xn + gamma*yn)*xnx + (alpha*ynx + beta*znx + tau*yn + upsilon*zn)*zn + (beta*xnx + gamma*ynx + upsilon*xn + chi*yn)*xn) + zB + zE]



   return [x_update,y_update,z_update]
```

---

Those first few were the most numerous. Lots of Search and Replace to do that and it has NOT been tested.

I found a term enclosed in parenthesis, searched and replaced all of them.  Looked for more patterns searched and replaced (`kappa` was really the only one here). `alpha1`, `beta1`, and `gamma1` were not necessary, they could have been included in the `kappa` assignment.

Maybe someone has a parser that can do that programmaticly(sp??) - I did it brute force.

---

So I couldn't help myself and tried to automate the search and replace. This is what I came up with - it should ensure a minimum number of repeat calcs. Again the result has NOT been tested as equivalent to the original statements.  after running this the new statements are in `new_statements`: just execute `print(new_statements.read())` to get a string that you can copy/paste into your function.:

```
import re, itertools, collections, io

s = '''
    x_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxx + ynxy + znxz) - 1.0*k22*(ynz - zny)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*ynz + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*zny - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*zny - (xnz - znx)*yny + (ynz - zny)*xny + (xnyy - ynxy)*zn - (xnyz - znxy)*yn + (ynyz - znyy)*xn)*zn + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znz - (xnz - znx)*ynz + (ynz - zny)*xnz + (xnyz - ynxz)*zn - (xnzz - znxz)*yn + (ynzz - znyz)*xn)*yn + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*(xny - ynx) + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*(xnz - znx)) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*xny + ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*yny + ((xny - ynx)*xny - (ynz - zny)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*xn - (ynyz - znyy)*zn)*xn + ((xny - ynx)*yny + (xnz - znx)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*yn + (xnyz - znxy)*zn)*yn) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*znz + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*xnz + ((xny - ynx)*ynz + (xnz - znx)*znz + (xnyz - ynxz)*yn + (xnzz - znxz)*zn)*zn + ((xnz - znx)*xnz + (ynz - zny)*ynz + (xnzz - znxz)*xn + (ynzz - znyz)*yn)*xn) + xB + xE

    y_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxy + ynyy + znyz) + k22*(xnz - znx)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*xnz - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*znx + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znx - (xnz - znx)*ynx + (ynz - zny)*xnx + (xnxy - ynxx)*zn - (xnxz - znxx)*yn + (ynxz - znxy)*xn)*zn - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znz - (xnz - znx)*ynz + (ynz - zny)*xnz + (xnyz - ynxz)*zn - (xnzz - znxz)*yn + (ynzz - znyz)*xn)*xn + k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*(xny - ynx) + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*(ynz - zny)) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*xnx + ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*ynx + ((xny - ynx)*xnx - (ynz - zny)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*xn - (ynxz - znxy)*zn)*xn + ((xny - ynx)*ynx + (xnz - znx)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*yn + (xnxz - znxx)*zn)*yn) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*znz - ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*ynz + ((xny - ynx)*xnz - (ynz - zny)*znz + (xnyz - ynxz)*xn - (ynzz - znyz)*zn)*zn - ((xnz - znx)*xnz + (ynz - zny)*ynz + (xnzz - znxz)*xn + (ynzz - znyz)*yn)*yn) + yB + yE

    z_update = -1.0*k11*(xnxz + ynyz + znzz) - 1.0*k22*(xny - ynx)*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn) - 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*xny + 1.0*k22*(q0 - (xny - ynx)*zn + (xnz - znx)*yn - (ynz - zny)*xn)*ynx - 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*znx - (xnz - znx)*ynx + (ynz - zny)*xnx + (xnxy - ynxx)*zn - (xnxz - znxx)*yn + (ynxz - znxy)*xn)*yn + 1.0*k22*((xny - ynx)*zny - (xnz - znx)*yny + (ynz - zny)*xny + (xnyy - ynxy)*zn - (xnyz - znxy)*yn + (ynyz - znyy)*xn)*xn - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*(ynz - zny) - ((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*(xnz - znx)) - 1.0*k33*(((xny - ynx)*xn - (ynz - zny)*zn)*zny - ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*yny + ((xny - ynx)*xny - (ynz - zny)*zny + (xnyy - ynxy)*xn - (ynyz - znyy)*zn)*zn - ((xnz - znx)*xny + (ynz - zny)*yny + (xnyz - znxy)*xn + (ynyz - znyy)*yn)*yn) + k33*(((xny - ynx)*yn + (xnz - znx)*zn)*znx + ((xnz - znx)*xn + (ynz - zny)*yn)*xnx + ((xny - ynx)*ynx + (xnz - znx)*znx + (xnxy - ynxx)*yn + (xnxz - znxx)*zn)*zn + ((xnz - znx)*xnx + (ynz - zny)*ynx + (xnxz - znxx)*xn + (ynxz - znxy)*yn)*xn) + zB + zE]

'''

term_names = itertools.combinations(string.ascii_uppercase,r=5)
new_statements = io.StringIO()

substitutions = {}
def f(s,pattern):
    '''Replace repeating terms with names and construct assignment statements.
    '''
    new_s = s
    c = collections.Counter(re.findall(pattern, s))
    for term, count in c.items():
        if count > 1:
            term_name = ''.join(next(term_names))
            substitutions[term] = term_name
            assignment = f'    {term_name} = {term}\n'
            new_statements.write(assignment)
            if term.startswith(r'('):
                sub = re.escape(term)
            elif '*' in term:
                sub = f'\\b{re.escape(term)}\\b'
            else:
                break
            new_s = re.sub(sub, term_name, new_s)
    return new_s, new_s != s

# keep a copy !!
original = s

pattern1 = r'\([^()]+\)'
pattern2 = r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\*[a-zA-Z]+\b'

while True:
    s, chng1 = f(s,pattern1)
    s, chng2 = f(s,pattern2)
    if not (chng1 or chng2):
        break


new_statements.write(s)
new_statements.seek(0)
#print(new_statements.read())
```

Comment: Thanks I have just implemented something similar and got a 30% increase in speed which is huge! Would you  happen to know if there was a general method to determine what operations were being repeated. This method seems highly dependent on the initial factorization to make it obvious what operations are being done multiple times (e.g. if one where to expand completely i don't think ctrl f and replace would work as well).